# Using a functor in a generic function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, functor, generic-programming

I have built a generic function which takes a certain container (using an Iterator for its beginning and end) and a Predicate (functor which serves as a some sort of condition check) and counts the number of pairs in that container which are true in the Predicate condition.
As the following

```
//Counts number of pairs in a container that follow the rule of the Predicate
template <typename Iterator, typename Predicate>
int countPairs(const Iterator first, const Iterator last, Predicate pred){
    int counter = 0;
    for(Iterator current = first; current<last; ++current){
        Iterator next(current);
        for(++next; next<last; ++next){
            if(pred(*current, *next)){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Then, i wanted to use the generic function in order to examine whether a certain vector is sorted. So i've built the following 'Predicate' which checks whether a pair of numbers is sorted:

```
bool isBigger(int a, int b){
    return b < a;
}
```

Then, i've built a function called which basically uses the two above in order to take a vector and check if its sorted:

```
bool isSorted(std::vector<int>& v){
    int size = v.size();
    if(size == 0 || size == 1){
        return true;
    }
    return countPairs(v.begin(), v.end(), isBigger()) == 0;
}
```

When I try to build, if provides me with the following errors:

> error: no matching function for call to 'isBigger'
>
> note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were
> provided

I'm pretty sure its because of the way I've used `isBigger` function in the `countPairs` calling. But that's how generic code works no?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `isBigger()` is a call to a function called "isBigger()" without any parameters. No such function is defined in the shown code. The only function defined that's named "isBigger()" takes two parameters, and returns a `bool`. Finally, the predicate is a callable function, and not a `bool` value. You obviously meant to pass a function pointer here, instead of making a function call. Do you know how to specify a function pointer, in C++?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you! Can you please show me how to use a function pointer in this example in order to make this work?

Comment: Would you believe `isBigger`, or perhaps `&isBigger`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik oh so its enough to just call the function's name? don't i have to define a function pointer seperately like in C?

Comment: You are not calling "the function's name" in `isSorted`. No call to this function takes place there. The pointer to the function is a callable object, or a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error carefully:

> error: **no matching function for call** to 'isBigger'
> note: candidate function not viable: **requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided**

You will immediately realise what went wrong. Instead of passing the function as argument, so that it can be called here:

```
            if(pred(*current, *next))
```

You called the function instead.

The fix is simple, instead of

```
return countPairs(v.begin(), v.end(), isBigger())
```

Pass the address of the function:

```
return countPairs(v.begin(), v.end(), &isBigger)
```

Also, you have written:

> Predicate (functor which serves as a some sort of condition check)

But you are not using any functors. A functor is just a class which defines `operator()`. In your case, you are using just a normal function. A functor would look like this:

```
struct _isBigger{
  bool operator()(int a, int b){
    return b < a;
  }
};

//and pass it to some function
return countPairs(v.begin(), v.end(), isBigger{})
```

Side note: You can also use a **lambda** instead which is basically like a function with no name:

```
return countPairs(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a, int b){
    return b < a;
}) == 0;
```

So beautiful, right? ;)

Also, your function isn't changing the `vector` parameter:

```
bool isSorted(std::vector<int>& v){
```

So, make it `const`:

```
bool isSorted(const std::vector<int>& v){
```

Comment: Thank you! Small question regarding that - i've used 

return countPairs(v.begin(), v.end(), isBigger)

without the '&' which takes the address of the function)
and it still works! as if i've provided the address of the function. Why is that?

Thanks again

Comment: They are exactly the same thing AFAIK. Both will end up with type `bool (*)(int, int)`. You can verify this at [CppInsights](https://cppinsights.io/) which is your best friend especially when writing template code and figuring out template errors.